# return to apple maps at different zoom

Tags: ios

I have a map of a zoo with pins that locate the animals. Zoom on the map. Tap on a pin then tap callout and it takes the user to a view with pic of animal and description/narrative. The "map" button on that view returns the user to the zoo map at the original zoom level. Does anyone know of a way to return to the map at the last zoom level/location?

Answer (score 0):

You can set what the region of what the user can see when your map gets displayed by using the

```
[self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
```

function. So what you want to do is, save the "region" property just when the map view is about to disappear so that you can set it again when the map view appears.